# AIX Package Install Issues

Tags: package, aix, rpm

I want to install gettext but i cannot because my AIX says that gettext is dependent on glib and when i try to install glib it says that I cannot because glib is in turn dependent on gettext.

Please let me know how I could get past this situation?

```
root [rover]% rpm -i gettext-0.17-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

error: failed dependencies: libglib-2.0.a(libglib-2.0.so.0) is needed by gettext-0.17-1

libxlsmp.a(smprt.o) is needed by gettext-0.17-1

root [rover]% rpm -i glib2-2.22.5-2.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

error: failed dependencies: gettext is needed by glib2-2.22.5-2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really have 2 problems:

1. error: failed dependencies: libglib-2.0.a(libglib-2.0.so.0) is needed by gettext-0.17-1
2. libxlsmp.a(smprt.o) is needed by gettext-0.17-1

The first error is indeed solved by what is said above (DO NOT use the --nodeps option in this case, it can cause really bad things to happen): use rpm -i (or -U for upgrade) to install both gettext and glib2 at the same time.  If you have both in the same directory you can just use `rpm -ihv (or -Uhv) *.rpm` to install all of the RPM's at once, and it will resolve interdependencies that way.

HOWEVER, you still will not likely be able to install gettext due to #2:  libxlsmp.a is a SECOND library/dependency that you need to solve.

It's my understanding that this library comes from a base AIX package (NOT an RPM/Open Source package) that will need to be installed from your AIX installation Media by installp.  According to other web research it's the "xlsmp" package.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass in both files at once for dependency resolution to work: `rpm -U gettext.rpm glib2.rpm`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work or not, but install one of the package ignoring the dependencies.
use --nodeps flag of rpm to do this. Once it is installed, then go ahead with the other package.

root [rover]% rpm **--nodeps** -i gettext-0.17-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

Make sure to resolve other dependencies (if any) later if you are following this.